# Regular expression for words in brackets

Tags: regex

Hi I am looking for the regular expression (C#) to match Hon. Ben Frank in the sentence below.

"The SPEAKER (Hon. Ben Frank)"

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you can search the following `regex`:

`\(([^\)]*)\)`

and the first captured group `\1` or `$1` is what you want

### Demo

Comment: I don't want to match the ( )

Comment: @Joesoc, See updated answer. The first captured group will contain only what's inside

Comment: How would I capture only the speaker if there was The President (Hon. xxx xxx) in the text along with The SPEAKER (Hon. Ben Frank).